# Increment column value automatically in every update

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I have created Entity having field as updateCount (non id column),
While first save.. I provide value = 1 for this column. But for every time if I update this entity , I want this column should auto increment.
Is there any way in Spring Jpa/Hibernate to do so? This will help to get latest update count for that record in case of concurrent update.

Answer (score 0):

use @Version int version in your model; spring does it for you automaitcally in every update

Comment: @Version basically keep track the Entity we are trying to update is latest one, In case our Entity updated by some concurrent Thread then it will throw Exception at the time of update. I don't want Exception.
I want something like for the value `set value (currentVal +1) at the time of repositoy.saveAndFlush()`